# Solr query - float range with boosting

Tags: solr, lucene

What is the proper way to implement following thing:

Task: query documents where voltage (float) equals *100.0* and tolerance *-0% / +20%*.

> q=+voltage_f[100.0 TO 120.0]

I want that documents with the **voltage near to lower bound (100.0) get more points** as the documents with the voltage near upper bound (120.0).

Or vice versa - tolerance *-20% / +0%*.

> q=+voltage_f[80.0 TO 100.0]

I want that documents with the **voltage near to upper bound (100.0) get more points** as the documents with the voltage near lower bound (80.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use the `recip` function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) to get a value that starts at 1 and then tapers off as the value increases:

> Performs a reciprocal function with `recip(x,m,a,b)` implementing `a/(m*x+b)` where m,a,b are constants, and x is any arbitrarily complex function.
>
> When a and b are equal, and x>=0, this function has a maximum value of 1 that drops as x increases. Increasing the value of a and b together results in a movement of the entire function to a flatter part of the curve. These properties can make this an ideal function for boosting more recent documents when x is rord(datefield).

For your first case, that could be implemented by using `recip` directly, and adjusting the `a` and `b` values to suit your needs.

For the second case you can use `abs(sub(100, x))` as `x`, as that becomes larger as the value is further away from 100.

The `recip` call can be added in `bf` (for dismax, edismax) or in `boost` (edismax).

Your frontend will have to decide the proper values to use for `a`, `b` or `m` - you can use `debugQuery=true` to see how much the boost contributes and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Works great with simple single-param queries.
Weight of other params affects the scoring. I tried to apply "negative boost" for other params and it works for now.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you can move those to either `fq` (which only filters and does not score), or sort by the function instead (if you don't want the score to count at all - but you probably do). Otherwise it's a matter of adjusting the weights to get the result which gives you the best relevancy for what you want to achieve.